# Pygame key holding not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame, sys, math

class Cam:
    def __init__(self, pos=(0,0,0), rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def update(self, dt, key):
        s = dt*10
        if key[pygame.K_r]: self.pos[1]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_f]: self.pos[1]+=s

        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[2]+=s
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[2]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0]+=s

pygame.init()
w,h = 400,400; cx,cy=w//2, h//2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

verts=(-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
edges = (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,4),(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)

cam = Cam((0,0,-5))

while True:
    dt = 0.1
    print dt
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        screen.fill((255,255,255))

        for edge in edges:
            points = []
            for x,y,z in (verts[edge[0]],verts[edge[1]]):

                x-=cam.pos[0]
                y-=cam.pos[1]
                z-=cam.pos[2]
                f=200/z
                x,y = x*f, y*f

                points = points + [(cx+int(x), cy+int(y))]
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), points[0], points[1], 1)

        pygame.display.flip()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        cam.update(dt, key)
```

This is my code. Pressing WASDRF should move the camera around constantly while holding the key, but no. It doesn't. I have to press the key each time I want to move one pixel. Can someone explain why holding the key doesn't work? Judging by all the other questions I've found, this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized my mistake so I thought i would post the answer myself. I put the entire rest of the code after the even for loop IN the event for loop meaning it would only update one every time an event like a key press happened. I needed to unindent everything past sys.exit()